# Angular ignores the animation duration

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I have a sidebar component which take the `sidebarExpanded` state from `Input()`. Whenever the input changes, the animation is triggered correctly but the width change appears instantly. The same animation code is working in another component, so is not a common `import` problem. The problem persists in different browsers. What am I missing here?

Thank you.

sidebar.component.ts

```js
import {
  animate,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('collapse', [
      state('false', style({ width: '0' })),
      state('true', style({ width: '25rem' })),
      transition('false <=> true', animate(1000)),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  @Input() sidebarExpanded = true;

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

sidebar.component.html

```html
<div class="sidebar" [@collapse]="sidebarExpanded"></div>
```

sidebar.component.scss

```css
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8rem;
  bottom: 0;

  background-color: var(--color-grey-dark-4);
  box-shadow: var(--shadow-dark);
}
```

Comment: animate(200) is in milliseconds, maybe too fast to notice the transition? Have you tried with longer transition?

Comment: yes, i tryied also with longer `animate()` but the transition appears instantly

Comment: You can also toggle a css class and let css do the animation.

Comment: are you sure that sidebarExpanded is changed from `true` to `false`?

Comment: @Andrei yes, logged and works correctly

Comment: Your code it's looks like work, I made a stackblitz with your code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nauxcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), check if you import the BrowserAnimationsModule (or NoopAnimationsModule if you are imported the browserAnimationModule in the main module and you're in another module) or try to execute again the `ng serve`. Check also if you are disabled the animations using `disableAnimations` when you import the Module

Answer (score 0):

I figured out i had placed the animation both on the div containing the sidebar and on the sidebar itself. Removing the animation from the parent `div` solved my problem.